# Exportar csv protegido por senha a partir de um DB

Tags: php, mysql, csv

É possível gerar um arquivo `CSV protegido por Senha` a partir de um  `banco MySql` usando `PHP`? a senha é para abrir o arquivo no cliente.

Utilizo este script PHP para gerar o arquivo CSV:

```
<?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "simrede"); 
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Falha ao fazer conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // Set utf8
      mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
      $connect->set_charset('utf8');
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Cadastro_Alunos-Simrede.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('lastname', 'firstname', 'department', 'institution', 'username',  'email', 'city', 'course1', 'password'),';');  
      $query = "SELECT * from cs_alunos ORDER BY institution";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row,";");  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: É preciso esclarecer se é necessária a senha para fazer a requisição do arquivo no servidor ou senha para abrir o arquivo no cliente.

Comment: @fernandosavio adicionada a informação no texto da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta rápida é que não tem como um arquivo CSV ser protegido por senha. Porém existem métodos pra chegar num resultado satisfatório.

Um deles seria compactar o `.csv` e proteger o `.zip` por senha. É um método eficiente porque, além de proteger o arquivo para leitura, também diminui o download do arquivo para o cliente.

No PHP um arquivo `.zip` pode ser criado usando a classe [`ZipArchive`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php).

Exemplo:

```php
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if($zip->open('download/meu_csv_protegido.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    return false;  // Não foi possível criar o zip
}

$zip->addFile('meus_dados.csv');
$zip->setPassword('minha_senha');
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Como fazer isso usando o script da pergunta cima?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de como criar um arquivo zip... Depois do `$zip->close()` é só enviar o arquivo para o cliente e, se for o caso, excluir o arquivo depois.